# How do I select a specific xmlnode and change it values

Tags: c#, xml

My xml looks like this....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<messwerte>
<messwert>
  <tag>1</tag>
  <niederschlag>46</niederschlag>
  <temperatur>7,6</temperatur>
  <druck>4,6</druck>
</messwert>
......
</messwerte>
```

Now, I wanna give a a specific day where I want to change "niederschlag" "temperatur" and "druck" and I tried this:

```
 public static void WriteXML(int day, double[] mess, string path)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(path);
           XmlElement nieder = doc.SelectSingleNode("/messwerte/messwert" + Convert.ToString(day) + "/niederschlag") as XmlElement;
           if (nieder != null)
           {
               nieder.InnerText = Convert.ToString(mess[0]);
           }
        }
```

And it wont work.
And I know it's baaaad and super basic but i cant get it to work.......

Comment: Check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-serializer !

Comment: Sample https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer?view=netframework-4.7.1

Comment: Without knowing what the value of the `day` (I have assumed a value of 3) parameter is, your xpath looks like this: `/messwerte/messwert3/niederschlag` and that doesn't match your xml. Can you specify which node you want to select under which criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the reason it won't work for you, is you're trying to do 2 different things with one xpath string.
First you have to find the `messwert` element with a `tag` element that has an InnerText value matching the `day` value you're passing in.
Once you've identified the right element you want to change the InnerText of the `niederschlag` element.

Even though writing this out makes it seem quite complicated, leveraging a LINQ query can simplify it tremendously:

```
public static void WriteXML(int day, double[] mess, string path)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(path);
    var nieder = (from XmlElement element in doc.GetElementsByTagName("messwert")
                         where element.SelectSingleNode("tag").InnerText == day.ToString()
                         select element).First().SelectSingleNode("niederschlag");
    if (nieder != null)
    {
        nieder.InnerText = mess[0].ToString();
    }
    doc.Save(path);
}
```

This code assumes your data is strongly controlled and that you'll never be looking for a day that isn't there.

If this isn't the case you'll have to assign the query including  the `First()` method to a temporary variable, and check if it's null.

Something like this should work:

```
public static void WriteXML(int day, double[] mess, string path)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(path);
    var messwert = (from XmlElement element in doc.GetElementsByTagName("messwert")
                    where element.SelectSingleNode("tag").InnerText == day.ToString()
                    select element).FirstOrDefault();
    if(messwert == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"The day value, doesn't exist.  the value passed is {day}");
    }
    var nieder = messwert.SelectSingleNode("niederschlag");
    if (nieder != null)
    {
        nieder.InnerText = mess[0].ToString();
    }
    doc.Save(path);
}
```